# Nested for and if loops in C

Tags: c, cs50

I've been working through Harvard's CS50 course and I have a question regarding design & use of nested for and if loops. I've submitted a problem set and I'm now just conducting a "post-mortem" to see if I could have written it more efficiently. In particular, I have a function which takes 2 arguments: a user's piece of text, and a 26-letter cipher key. it then converts the plain text into cipher text by replacing each character with the corresponding cipher key value.

I was wondering if the way I have written it here would be considered poor design? Having layers of for and if loops seems very clunky to me. (In particular looping through my alphabet string for each character, then reassigning that character to the corresponding cipher key, seems convoluted?)

Thanks,

```
// function for converting plain text to cipher text
string substitution(string text, string cipher)
{
    string alphabet = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    
    
    // for each character:
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
    {
        // check if character is in the alphabet:
        if ((text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z') || (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            // find position in alphabet by index, then convert to same index in the cipher string
            for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
            {
                if (text[i] == alphabet[j])
                {
                    text[i] = cipher[j];
                    break;
                }
                if (text[i] + 32 == alphabet[j])
                {
                    text[i] = cipher[j] - 32;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Nested loops and conditional statements are not inherently bad, but in this case your function is indeed more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: Not what you asked, but `isalpha()` (in ctype.h) is handy.

Comment: Why add 32? Instead could  `text[i] ^ ('a' ^ 'A')`.  Self documenting. and works  with EBCIDIC,

Comment: `if` is not a loop construct.

Comment: regarding: `for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)`  the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`  (unsigned long).  This statement is comparing a unsigned value to a signed value, always a bad idea.  Suggest: `for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used this for checking if `text[i]` is an alphabet instead of `isalpha()`, so I assume you limit the target environment of your program to where character code for alphabets are continuous (like ASCII).

```
        if ((text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z') || (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z'))
```

Under this limitation, you can simply subtract `'a'` or `'A'` to get the indice of characters without using loops to find the character.

This means the inner loop part

```
            for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
            {
                if (text[i] == alphabet[j])
                {
                    text[i] = cipher[j];
                    break;
                }
                if (text[i] + 32 == alphabet[j])
                {
                    text[i] = cipher[j] - 32;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

can be written as

```
            if (text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z')
            {
                text[i] = cipher[text[i] - 'a'];
            }
            else
            {
                text[i] = cipher[text[i] - 'A'] - 32;
            }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `else` part be an `else if (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z')` so that for non alpha characters you don't index cipher?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Originally no because the `if` statement is intended to be in the `if ((text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z') || (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z'))` statement, but I noticed that it is better not to nest `if` statement like this and to use `if (text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z')` and `else if (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z')` in the loop.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I just didn't read your answer properly...

Answer (score 0):

You can compact the character search using `strchr` function, which does... the same thing you do. Not much efficiency gain in there.

To calculate the index you can use direct subtraction:

```
// check if character is in the alphabet:
if ((text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z') {
    j = text[i]-'a';
    text[i] = cipher[j];
} else if ((text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z') {
    j = text[i]-'A';
    text[i] = cipher[j] + 32;
}
```

You could also pre-calculate a table of all 255 possible char values (zero excluded), and set the value to zero if the character must not be ciphered, the cipher value otherwise.

Then:

```
for (i = 0; text[i]; i++) {
    if (table[text[i]]) {
        text[i] = table[text[i]];
    }
}
```

This makes sense if you need to cipher long texts, of course, otherwise you spend more in calculating the table than in using it.

Also, since the branching is on many architectures more expensive than simply assigning, consider MikeCAT's excellent suggestion whereby the "non-cipher" characters are replaced by themselves, so that `text[i] = table[text[i]]` actually does nothing:

```
for (i = 0; text[i]; i++) {
    text[i] = table[text[i]];
}
```

Comment: Consider setting `table[c] = c` instead of zero for no-cipher characters `c`. This will save the branch `if (table[text[i]])`.

Comment: @MikeCAT excellent suggestion, amended answer.

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick a bit easier

```
string substitution(string text, string cipher)
{    
    // for each character:
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
    {
        // check if character is in the alphabet:
        if (text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z') 
        {
            text[i] = cipher[text[i] - 97]; // index of 'a' in alphabet is 97
        }
        else if (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            text[i] = cipher[text[i] - 65] - 32; // index of 'A' in alphabet is 65
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use hard-to-read magic numbers `97` and `65` in the indice while using character literals in the conditions?

Comment: Also now you won't need the variable `alphabet`.

Comment: because it also explains something new, that characters are integers too and have their fixed codes, therefore I also put a comment there

Comment: true, removed it

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to make assumptions about the character code ordering and relationships such as upper/lowercase conversion, then the `alphabet` array serves little purpose.  Its only purpose can be to decouple the code from platform defined character set ordering.

In practice it is probably a fair bet that your assumptions are valid for any platform you are likely to encounter, but if you are going to define `alphabet` then you should perhaps be consistent and make the rest of the code independent of the platform character-set.  To do that you should use the `ctype.h` header.   The following code does that and also eliminates some other issues such as "magic numbers".

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// function for converting plain text to cipher text
string substitution(string text, string cipher)
{
    static const char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    static const size_t ALPHABET_LEN = sizeof(alphabet) / sizeof(*alphabet) ;
    
    // for each character:
    size_t text_len = strlen( text ) ;
    for( int i = 0; i < text_len; i++ )
    {
        // check if character is in the alphabet:
        if( isalpha( text[i] ) )
        {
            // find position in alphabet by index, then convert to same index in the cipher string
            for (int j = 0; j < ALPHABET_LEN; j++)
            {
                bool is_upper = isupper( text[i] ) ;
                if( !is_upper && text[i] == alphabet[j])
                {
                    text[i] = cipher[j];
                    break;
                }
                else if( is_upper && tolower(text[i]) == alphabet[j])
                {
                    text[i] = toupper( cipher[j] ) ;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return text;
}
```

It is perhaps a matter of opinion, but many coding standards allow `break` only as a switch-case delimiter. `break` and `continue` for aborting a loop can create poor and confusing structure and control flow and can make debugging more complex as the control flow can "jump over" break-points.  To avoid the use of `break`:

```
        bool match = false ;
        for (int j = 0; !match && j < ALPHABET_LEN; j++)
        {
            bool is_upper = isupper( text[i] ) ;
            if( !is_upper && text[i] == alphabet[j])
            {
                text[i] = cipher[j];
                match = true ;
            }
            else if( is_upper && tolower(text[i]) == alphabet[j] )
            {
                text[i] = toupper( cipher[j] ) ;
                match = true ;
            }
        }
```